# How to compare Rails ''executables" before and after refactor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, rubinius

In C, I could generate an executable, do an extensive rename only refactor, then compare executables again to confirm that the executable did not change. This was very handy to ensure that the refactor did not break anything.

Has anyone done anything similar with Ruby, particularly a Rails app?  Strategies and methods would be appreciated. Ideally, I could run a script that output a single file of some sort that was purely bytecode and was not changed by naming changes. I'm guessing JRuby or Rubinus would be helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this strategy will work for Ruby.  Unlike C, where the compiler throws away the names, most of the things you name in Ruby carry that name with them.  That includes classes, modules, constants, and instance variables.

Automated unit and integration tests are the way to go to support Ruby refactoring.

Comment: Actually, nothing beats comparing the .exe and seeing they are *exactly* the same, guaranteeing there is nothing different, rather than trusting test coverage ;-).  I'm a firm believer in writing tests, but would like to be able to make simple rename refactors to a huge legacy app with bad test coverage and my way is much more quick and certain to catch changes.  That's the point of my question.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question -- I like the definitive "yes" answer you can get from this regression strategy, at least for the specific case of rename refactoring.

I'm not expert enough to tell whether you can compile ruby (or at least a subset, without things like `eval`) but there seem to be some hints at:

- http://www.hokstad.com/the-problem-with-compiling-ruby.html
- http://rubini.us/2011/03/17/running-ruby-with-no-ruby/

Supposing that a complete compilation isn't possible, what about an abstract interpretation approach?  You could parse the ruby into an AST, emit some kind of C code from the AST, and then compile the C code.  The C code would not need to fully capture the behavior of the ruby code.  It would only need to be compilable and to be distinct whenever the ruby was distinct.  (Actually running it could result in gibberish, or perhaps an immediate memory violation error.)

As a simple example, suppose that ruby supported multiplication and C didn't.  Then you could include a static `mult` function in your C code and translate from:
   `a = b + c*d`
to
   `a = b + mult(c,d)`
and the resulting compiled code would be invariant under name refactoring but would show discrepancies under other sorts of change.  The `mult` function need not actually implement multiplication, you could have one of these instead:

```
static int mult( int a, int b ) { return a + b; } // pretty close
static int mult( int a, int b ) { return *0; } // not close at all, but still sufficient
```

and you'd still get the invariance you need as long as the C compiler isn't going to inline the definition.  The same sort of translation, from an uncompilable ruby construct to a less functional but distinct C construct, should work for object manipulation and so forth, mapping class operations into C structure references.  The key point is just that you want to keep the naming relationships intact while sacrificing actual behavior.

(I wonder whether you could do something with a single C struct that has members (all pointers to the same struct type) named after all the class and property names in the ruby code.  Class and object operations would then correspond to nested dereference operations using this single structure.  Just a notion.)

Even if you cannot formulate a precise mapping, an imprecise mapping that misses some minor distinctions might still be enough to increase confidence in the original name refactoring.

The quickest way to implement such a scheme might be to map from byte code to C (rather from the ruby AST to C).  That would save a lot of parsing, but the mapping would be harder to understand and verify.